# How to import go package as underscore "_"?

Tags: go

Since `_` is used in Go as a blank identifier to discard value. The import statement below will import the package and execute its `init` function. Is there a way to alias the package as `_`? so that I can use it as `_.Method()`.

```
import (
    _ "github.com/ziutek/mymysql/godrv"
)
```

Comment: why not just use any other single character if you're trying to obfuscate the package name?

Comment: @JimB I'm curios if it might has any workaround for `_` as alias. I can totally use any characters as an alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible, for the reason you described. The closest you can do is use two underscores:

```
import (
    __ "github.com/ziutek/mymysql/godrv"
)
```

```
__.Method()
```